# Azure Active Directory cannot add a permission

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

I've been following this tutorial to set up a AAD api and ran into an issue.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

> Grant permissions in Azure AD
>   Now that you have registered two applications to represent the API and the Developer Console, you need to grant permissions to allow the client-app to call the backend-app.
>
> 1. Navigate to App registrations.
> 2. Select client-app, and in the list of pages for the app go to API permissions.
> 3. Select Add a Permission.
> 4. Under Select an API, find and select backend-app.
> 5. Under Delegated Permissions, select the appropriate permissions to `backend-app`.
> 6. Select Add permissions

On step 3, when I try to look for my backend app, I can't find it in the my org list or my apis.

[here are my apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdyXE.png)

[here I try to look for the backend app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSwhi.png)

And under my apis, it shows nothing.

Comment: "I can't find it " - What is "it"?

Comment: the dummy backend api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were no admin groups to accept incoming requests. so under the backend app I needed to go to expose an api and create a scope.